# How to i add 24 hours to 12 hours timestamp with AM and PM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timestamp

I made below code for getting real time. but i don't understand, how to i add timestamp 24 hours to 12 hours and AM PM.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var realTime = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds
  $('#time').html(realTime);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Try to use `date-fns` library. It's lightweight and powerfull

Comment: use momentjs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this approach (*comments inline*)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var seconds = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
  var minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var amPM = hours < 12 ? "AM": "PM"; //decides if this is AM or PM based on hours value
  hours = ("0" + (hours % 12)).slice(-2); //pad 0 prefix 
  var realTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + " " + amPM; //prepare the date format
  $('#time').html(realTime);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: can i run hours without zero `0` . if i remove zero from here `hours = ("0" + (hours % 12)).slice(-2);` to `hours = ("" + (hours % 12)).slice(-2);` now time showing me without zero. is it alright?

Comment: Yes, in that case, you can also remove the `slice(-2)` as well, just keep it `hours  = (hours % 12)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var now = moment().format("hh:mm:ss a");
  $('#time').html(now);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and format using `format("hh:mm:ss a")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  if (hours > 12){hours = hours -12; amPM = ' PM'}else{amPM = ' AM'}
  var realTime = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds + amPM
  $('#time').html(realTime);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not well accepted in SO. Also, your code produced 15:22:22 PM which is wrong.

Comment: @VTodorov his code outputs 13:24:40 PM for me, which is correct. Maybe it depends on where you are?

Comment: @MasterYoda 13 PM is wrong. It should be 1 PM. Isn't that the idea of using AM/PM ?